# Barnes-Hut and recursion limit

Tags: c++, recursion, stack-overflow

I have implemented the "Barnes-Hut" algorithm into my n-body simulator, and I have run into a problem.

My program will crash, with memory related exceptions, mainly a `stack overflow` exception.

The thing that makes this a strange error to receive is that it does not occur at fixed times, it seems to come out of the blue. Using task manager I can clearly see there is no memory leak, and I have been very careful to avoid this. I do though, use recursion, and objects with in objects.

Is it possible that I will need to include a maximum depth of the oct-tree and this is what is causing the error?

Comment: Could you show the code? If you're using recursion, whose depth is depended on the depth of an Oct tree, then yes, this might be the issue. How deep are your trees? Can you transform the algorithm to an imperative version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximal recursion depth is indeed limited by the stack size.
The stack size is **not** the same as your full RAM memory size.
Eg. on Windows, the default stack size (per thread) is 1MB, nothing more.

It´s possible to reconfigure it for your program, and/or to "catch" the stack overflow error without the whole program crashing (latter is rather dirty, but at least possible).

Nonetheless the best solution would be a modified code to get rid of that recursion. All recursions can be replaced with iterative solutions, but it probably will be a bit more complicated. And the data of each function call can be moved to a vector etc. with one entry per call, so that the dynamic allocated vector memory can use the whole RAM.

Comment: Added maximum depth to the oct-tree, and their for a maximum depth of the recursive function, I have not had any more crashes.